# CSS темы на вордпрессе

Tags: css, wordpress

Есть два момента, которые своими силами я все никак не могу довести до ума:

1) Притарабанить фоновую картинку в подвале к самому дну океана + сделать ее адаптивной для различных устройств. На данный момент картинку я поставил, но на некоторых экранах 1200+ появляется белый отступ под картинкой, а на мобильных устройствах с малым экраном она вовсе занимает 1\5 подвала. Пронаблюдать можно здесь - http://apex-mountain.ru/

Я добавлял такой незамысловатый код:

```
footer.main-footer {
background-image: url(ссылка на изображение)!important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;}
```

2) Добавления CSS в posts page. У всех моих страниц одинаковый дизайн в верхней части. Текст, слева иллюстрация и снизу линия, на которой стоит иллюстрация. Страница на сайте "О нас". Добавить изображение не смог из-за ограничения сервиса.

Но на странице posts page (в моем случае это Блог) я не могу внести CSS стили, чтобы подвинуть иллюстрацию на уровень линии. После внесения через инструмент добавления стилей ничего не происходит. Страница на сайте "Блог". Добавить изображение не смог из-за ограничения сервиса.

Собственно говоря, контора, у которой я приобрел данную платную тему, сказала, что именно на этой странице нельзя вносить CSS стили. Есть ли способ внести изменения ? Я так понимаю, что CSS я вношу через инструмент разработанный создателями темы.

[image: css шайтан-коробка]

Comment: Это два вопроса. Поскольку на первый уже ответили - второй удали отсюда и вынеси его в отдельный.

Comment: @SeVlad  Да неправильно на первый ответили. Дело вообще не в этом.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, я в см - "начали отвечать". Иначе можно  было смело тревогу жмакать;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Дело совсем не в стилях background подвала. Работает некий дикий скрипт, который при смене ширины экрана пересчитывает высоту блока `#ncf-body-bg`, да так дивно, что она становится больше высоты body. Что и вызывает дырку внизу. Ищите, что такое ncf sidebar и какой плагин его выводит. Отключайте. Или добавьте в `style.css` следующее:

```
div#ncf-body-bg {
  display: none;
}
```

2) Контора ответила справедливо. На "страницу" блог нельзя вносить изменения вот таким способом, через стили Visual Composer, потому что "Блог" - это и не страница вовсе. Но тем не менее, стили править можно. Чтобы "посадить" альпиниста на линию, эту линию надо поднять выше, что и сделано на странице "О нас". Для "Блог" в файл `style.css` надо добавить следующий стиль:

```
.blog .vc_row:nth-child(3) .vc_col-sm-12>.vc_column-inner {
  margin-top: -39px;
}
```

Но это паллиатив. На широком экране ОК, при узких экранах между линией и картинкой - разрыв. Так же как и на странице "О нас". Верстку надо менять.

Answer (score 0):

1) `background-size: cover;` (превентивно и твои запросы вроде покрывает)

2) К сожалению (а может к счастью) в вордпресс я не умею =/